# Infinite loop useEffect with useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

```
// get state
const { inscriptions } = useSelector( state => state.user );

// flag
const instances = Object.keys(inscriptions).length;

// dispatch
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const getInscriptions = () => dispatch( getInscriptionsAction() );

useEffect( () => {
    // call api only if empty
    if(instances === 0) {
        const queryToAPI = async () => {
            getInscriptions();
        }
        
        queryToAPI();
    }
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [ instances, inscriptions ]);
```

My problem is, whenever i call the API inside de useEffect that forces a store update, which makes the component to re-render and thus initiating the infinite loop. I can't either put something like `if(isntances === 0) return null;` or so below useEffect becouse my inscriptions  array CAN be empty i tried adding all kind of flags but it keeps infinite looping. Any ideas?

==================EDIT================================
Okay now I've implemented some suggestions, but the problem still remains, the infinite loop stills.

```
// get state
const { inscriptions } = useSelector( state => state.user );

// flag
const instances = Object.keys(inscriptions).length;

// dispatch
const dispatch = useDispatch();

// const getInscriptions = () => dispatch( getInscriptionsAction() );

const getInscriptions = useCallback(
    () => dispatch( getInscriptionsAction() ),
    [ dispatch, getInscriptionsAction ]
);

useEffect( () => {
    // call api only if empty
    if(instances === 0) {
        // const queryToAPI = async () => {
            getInscriptions();
        // }
        
        // queryToAPI();
    }
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [ ]);
```

Comment: Why is `inscriptions` a dependency of the effect but `getInscriptions` isn't? Use `useCallback` for getInscriptions and make that a dependency.

Comment: what does your inscriptions look like ?

Comment: Since `inscriptions` is an array so, every time the component re renders a new reference gets created for the array and eventually it calls the useEffect since `inscriptions` is a dependency for useEffect hook in your example.

Comment: @aravind_reddy it's simply and array of objects

Comment: @HMR like so ? `const getInscriptions = useCallback(
        () => dispatch( getInscriptionsAction() )
    )

    useEffect( () => {
        // call api only if empty
        if(instances === 0) {
            
            getInscriptions();
        }
        
        
    }, [ inscriptions, instances, getInscriptions ]);`

Comment: @Arindam yeh, the point is i need either inscriptiosn itself or instances to be a depencency, becouse my component depends on them changes, what would work better  use only instances as a dependency?

Comment: see whenyou compare two objects in js they aren't equal its always false/different so you are running into infinte loop

Comment: @FranM make dispatch and getInscriptionsAction a dependency of the useCallback, they are both static functions and won't change so it's only created when component mounts but adding them will keep the linter happy. You don't even have to check instances.length and just run it on mount.

Comment: can you create a simple codesanbox of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figure it out, one of my types in the Reducer rested de inscriptions to and empty array, so it was re-rendering infinitely.